# #1366 - Incorrect integer value:MYsql

Tags: mysql, sql

hi every one  i have a problem in mysql

my table is

```
          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contactform` (
                  `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                  `addition` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                     `surname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                  `Address` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
                   `postalcode` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
                        `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                      `phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
                      `emailaddress` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
                           `dob` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                               `howtoknow` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                          `othersource` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                             `orientationsession` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
                               `othersession` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
                                  `organisation` int(11) NOT NULL,
                                      `newsletter` int(2) NOT NULL,
                                      `iscomplete` int(11) NOT NULL,
                          `registrationdate` date NOT NULL,
                            PRIMARY KEY (`contact_id`)
                     ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=39 ;



             mysql>insert into contactform values('','abhi','sir','shukla','vbxcvb','342342','asdfasd','234234234','abhi@gmail.com','1999/5/16','via vrienden of familie','','19','20','6','1','1','2010-03-29')
```

i get following error.
                           #1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'contact_id' at row 1

this query work fine on my local machine but give error on server

Answer (score 23):

Had the same problem with some legacy project. I didn't want to turn off strict mode globally, but also didn't want to go through all the code to fix it, so I disabled it only within that application by executing the following query once after the connection to the db is made:

```
SET sql_mode = ""
```

Comment: Please elaborate on this.  Where exactly? On each model methods? I have the same problem and quite a few models with several methods. Didn't see a way to include in database.php either.  Although, there is a $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE; line that apparently is not helping.

Answer (score 21):

Try using `NULL` instead of `''` for `contact_id` in

```
insert into contactform values(NULL,......
```

Comment: @Rajanikant: You are welcome :). Also since you are new to Stack overflow, I would like to inform you that you can accept an answer that helped you the most by checking the tick mark next to the Answer.

Comment: @codaddict I've got the same problem with MySQL Community Server 5.6.26, but MySQL complains that I can't insert `NULL` into a non-`NULL` column. Is there some way around it, apart from running `SET SQL_MODE = '';` before the `INSERT`?

Comment: He doesn"t deserve his gold badge as he didn't accept the answer... :|

Answer (score 10):

Try to find following line in my.cnf/my.ini:

```
sql-mode=”STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION”
```

Now comment it out with # and restart your mysql server.

Comment: It's probably better to fix the errors rather than just convert them to warnings by turning off strict mode.

Answer (score 6):

'' is an empty string, you want a integer, but this integer is created by the database. Drop the columnname in the INSERT and don't insert any value.

Answer (score 0):

`''` is not an integer, is it?

Also, that is some seriously weird indentation.

Comment: It works fine when you have a MySQL-server without propper configuration. See the SQL MODE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html A good configuration will produce errors when you do something wrong. Inserting a string into a integer field, is wrong.

Comment: it is not also apple so we can say here is zero apple.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql console, try this:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing - make sure your CSV/TXT file is UTF-8 WITHOUT the BOM - the BOM will pass characters that are not intgers and MySQL will think you are importing that into the first field...