# My php/sql scripts works on local server but incompletely on live site

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wrote scripts to function as a CMS for 2 sets of databases, an image gallery and menu. They work on local servers that I tested on windows, mac and even linux using xampp and mamp.

But on the live site on GoDaddy, the menu cms can only modify database items and won't add a new one. The gallery cms can only upload images, but also won't add the database item like its supposed to.

I appreciate any tips as to how to debug this issue or any possible solutions (still have a lot to learn about PDOs, php, and sql).

The PDO file I require in(changed database credentials):

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

define('APP_ROOT', __DIR__);
define('VIEW_ROOT', APP_ROOT . '/views');
define('BASE_URL', '');

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=menu','sqladmin', 'password');

require 'functions.php';
?>
```

Here is the image upload script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['files'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $file=> $name) {
        $filename = date('Ymd-His',time()).mt_rand().'-'.$name;
        try {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$file],'../uploads/'.$filename)){
                $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO multiupload VALUES('',?)");
                $stmt->bindParam(1, $filename);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e;
        }

    }
}
?>
```

and the add item to menu script:

```
<?php 

        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $name       = $_POST['name'];
            $label      = $_POST['label'];          
            $dsc        = $_POST['dsc'];
            $price      = $_POST['price'];
            $price2     = $_POST['price2'];
            $price3     = $_POST['price3'];
            $price4     = $_POST['price4'];

            $insertPage = $db->prepare("
                INSERT INTO menu (name, label, dsc,price,price2,price3,price4)
                VALUE (:name, :label, :dsc, :price,:price2,:price3,:price4)
            ");

            $insertPage->execute([
                'name'      => $name,
                'label'     => $label,
                'dsc'       => $dsc,
                'price'     => $price,
                'price2'    => $price2,
                'price3'    => $price3,
                'price4'    => $price4,
            ]);

            header('Location: ' . BASE_URL . '/admin/list.php');
        }

?>
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO multiupload VALUES('',?)` - any reason why the first value is left empty and the second is parameterized? It can be parameterized with an empty string too.

Comment: First, look for version differences on PHP, MySQL, etc. Then check permissions in mysql for the web server user.

Comment: if you were to check for the real errors, maybe you'd know why your code failed.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena the first value is an auto incrementing id so no need to parameterize it I suppose.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I've already attempted to check for those differences and actually thought it might be due to GoDaddy's servers only being on php 5.6, but I tested on 5.6 with xampp, and it worked there. Would minor version differences even matter though with SQL and db server type?

Comment: @Fred-ii- How would I go about doing that? I looked into php/sql debugging, but could still use some tips.

Comment: Start with the basics, turn on php errors with ```error_reporting(E_ALL); 
``` and ```ini_set('display_errors', '1');```. Add checks for sql errors after each call (mysqli? PDO? - can't tell from your code)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

How I would go about debugging this issue:

- Make sure that insert query gets called
- Check what `execute()` returns for this query
- Dump query and try executing it in mysql client. Of course replace placeholders with real values.

Comment: Would be grateful for feedback as to how it does not answer the "**I appreciate any tips as to how to debug this issue** or any possible solutions"

Comment: Can you elaborate on the first 2? (Not sure why you were downvoted, your advice is appreciated btw!)

Comment: I found an issue with my file upload script with the statement INSERT INTO multiupload VALUES('',?).
Apparently the empty string wouldn't insert into integer value on Godaddy's sql server, but it would on my local server b/c it isn't configured. I got the error #1366 in the sql client upon attempting your 3rd suggestion, simply googled that and found this solution pretty much explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536199/1366-incorrect-integer-valuemysql 
wish I could upvote you! xD

Comment: Oh, yes, differences in configuration. Those bugs can really be a nightmare,
 but I'm happy that you found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

My database was in strict SQL mode so I had to change a few lines in my script where I had data types being inserted that weren't necessarily the specific data type set for my SQL items. On my local servers, empty SQL inputs would work even the the data type wasn't necessarily matching. There were 2 SQL insertions that had this data type issue. One in the image upload script where

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO multiupload VALUES('',?)");
```

I simply replaced the empty string with null. The other in the menu's add item script where if an added menu item only had one price option, the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th price would be left blank on the form input which would result in a null value being inserted to the SQL table's integer data type. So I added javascript to that page,

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName('pricex');      

function makeDefault(){
    var input = document.getElementsByClassName('pricex');

    if(input.value.length == 0){

        x = input.length;
        console.log(x);     
        for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            input.getElementsByClassName('.pricex')[i].value = 0.00;
        }
    }
}
```

ensuring that the value for blank prices would be changed to the integer 0.00 rather than the original default value, null that resulted in the data type issue.

Thanks xReprisal for this suggestion that was all I needed to debug and solve the issue:

> Dump query and try executing it in mysql client. Of course replace
>   placeholders with real values.