# MySQL insert null doesn't work after server update

Tags: php, mysql

I have recently updated my server from 14.04 to 16.04 (Ubuntu that is) and by doing so I also updated the MySQL and PHP server to:

Server version: 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

PHP version: 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Since than quite a few of my apps started misbehaving and it's all to do with NULL.

Looking at an example, here is the PHP code:

```
$stmt=$db->prepare($query);
$stmt=$db->execute($data);
```

But this result in: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'id' at row 1
```

Trying to do a `print_r` of $query and $data this is what it returns:

```
insert into `company` (`id`,`Name`,`customerid`,`named_person`,`email`,`contact_no`,`payment_term`,`billing_contact`,`billing_email`,`billing_add1`,`billing_add2`,`billing_postcode`,`docketmail`,`livefeed`,`auto_populate`,`risk`,`question`,`livefeed_pass`,`livefeed_user`,`owner`) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) on duplicate key update`Name`=?,`customerid`=?,`named_person`=?,`email`=?,`contact_no`=?,`payment_term`=?,`billing_contact`=?,`billing_email`=?,`billing_add1`=?,`billing_add2`=?,`billing_postcode`=?,`docketmail`=?,`livefeed`=?,`auto_populate`=?,`risk`=?,`question`=?,`livefeed_pass`=?,`livefeed_user`=?

Array
(
    [0] => NULL
    [1] => sdasdasd
    [2] => 0
    [3] => sdasdasd
    [4] => asdasdas
    [5] => sdasdasd
    [6] => 14
    [7] => dadasdsad
    [8] => asdsadasd
    [9] => dasdasdas
    [10] => dasdasdsad
    [11] => dasdasdas
    [12] => 
    [13] => 0
    [14] => 1
    [15] => 0
    [16] => 0
    [17] => 
    [18] => 
    [19] => 1
    [20] => sdasdasd
    [21] => 0
    [22] => sdasdasd
    [23] => asdasdas
    [24] => sdasdasd
    [25] => 14
    [26] => dadasdsad
    [27] => asdsadasd
    [28] => dasdasdas
    [29] => dasdasdsad
    [30] => dasdasdas
    [31] => 
    [32] => 0
    [33] => 1
    [34] => 0
    [35] => 0
    [36] => 
    [37] => 
)
```

This worked before updating the server.

innodb is running in strict mode off.

### Update

The solution [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536199/1366-incorrect-integer-valuemysql) helps but I feel this is a workaround rather than a fix and will still like to get it fixed properly.

Comment: is `id` set as auto increment in MySQL? What data are you passing for `id` in this query?

Comment: Yes id is set to auto increment. I'm passing the exact array I'm showing in the question.

Comment: You can remove the `id` from your insert query and mysql will handle it.

Comment: yes but I have quite a few applications and there are logics to it, see for example this is insert on duplicate update, meaning the array can be an update array so removing the id isn't a viable solution for me. Sorry.

Comment: This behavior should not be changed from MySql 5.6 to 5.7 I think that it may be probably a PDO issue, not sure though. Read this [MySql doc article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) and try to force it to start in the mixed mode and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.

Reading: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_error_for_division_by_zero and looking at the table below, I have adjusted `my.cnf` as follows:

```
 sql_mode=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO
```

and now it works as I expected it, not sure why it got wrong in first place.

```
+---------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| Desired Behavior                | MySQL 5.7.x Versions Except 5.7.4 Through 5.7.7                                  | MySQL 5.7.4 Through 5.7.7 |
+---------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| insert NULL, produce no warning | ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO not enabled                                           | strict mode not enabled   |
| insert NULL, produce warning    | ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, or ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO + strict mode + IGNORE | strict mode + IGNORE      |
| error                           | ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO + strict mode                                         | strict mode               |
+---------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
```