# MySQL/Laravel handling null values when saving model

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-design, null, eloquent

When saving my form, it saves properly and all, but if a value in the form was blank, it will fail to save, even if the column was set to allow null.

As a result, the only way to get it to work seems to be checking if the value exists, otherwise set it to null manually (seen below).

```
$model = \Blah\Model::where(blahblah)->first;
$model->value = $value ? $value : null;
$model->save();
```

I have issues doing this though too just because if a value was 0 (zero), it would set it to null because of the way php interprets conditionals.

I don't want to have to do this for every value in every model.  So is there a way to make it properly handle null values so that if the field was blank it will save null into the model at that column instead of giving me an error?

So basically is there a way to properly handle null values in SQL/eloquent that will keep 0 value, and if it's blank, properly save null value?

Edit:  The generated query

```
General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'Strength' at row 1 (SQL: update `playerstats` set `Strength` = where `id` = 1)
```

Comment: @ccloyed mention laravel version please?

Comment: What is the Error message in your logfile if it fails to save? And please show your Model!

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL.

Comment: Googling the SQL error turns up many hits about `sql_mode`, does it help?
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536199/1366-incorrect-integer-valuemysql

Answer (score 0):

You should use below code :

```
$model = \Blah\Model::where(blahblah)->first;

if($modal->value == "0") {
  $model->value = 0;
}
else{
  $model->value = NULL;
}
$model->save();
```

Comment: Yea I can do that.  But the main issue is I don't want to wrap all the values in if statements, as it will be over 100 columns as the page grows.  I'd rather figure out how to get the database entities to properly interpret zero as zero  and (NULLstr) as null.

Comment: @cclloyd: Try to changing your column datatype as "VARCHAR".

Answer (score 0):

make the `value` column on your model `nullable`

and use `$model->value = isset( $value ) ? $value : null;`